# MercurialHG and TortoiseHG code repository origin

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

I'm quite new to Mercurial and Tortoise and am trying to find the origin (repository) of a particular project that I have on one of our servers. Can anyone tell me where this very useful nugget of information is found in the interface, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, when a repo is cloned, the `default` repo is set in the `[paths]` section of the hgrc file. Here's how you can see those paths:

1. Right click on the repo in the Tortoise's Repository Registry
2. Select `settings`
3. On the settings tab *for the repo*, click `Edit File`
4. In the `[paths]` section, there should be a `default=` entry

Please note: that file is editable and may no longer reflect from where that instance was cloned. This is akin to looking at a file in your file system: you have no record of the historical provenance.

Comment: That's cracked it.  Thanks Edward.  I can't believe it's so hidden.  I could understand it in a static GIT environment, where the repository is centralised, but with something as fluid as Mercurial (Ha! The name's right!) I would have thought that knowing where the code was cloned *from* would have been a key requirement.

Comment: Glad it helped! I often edit that setting (I typically work with hg in the console) because I clone from a local repo and then point it to the repo on the server.